# Как мне прибавить +3 часа к значению? (Вывод текущий даты и времени в картинке)

Tags: javascript, php

Время на картинке отоброжается неверно необходимо прибавить 3 часа к переменной **$fct_hour**.
Вот код картинки часов.

```
<?php
#http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php List of Time Zones
function showclienttime()
{
    if(!isset($_COOKIE['GMT_bias']))
    {
     ?>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var Cookies = {};
            Cookies.create = function (name, value, days) {
                if (days) {
                    var date = new Date();
                    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
                    var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
                }
                else {
                    var expires = "";
                }
                document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
                this[name] = value;
            }

            var now = new Date();
            Cookies.create("GMT_bias",now.getTimezoneOffset(),1);
            window.location = "<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>";
        </script>

        <?php

    }
    else {
      $fct_clientbias = $_COOKIE['GMT_bias'];
    }

    $fct_servertimedata = gettimeofday();
    $fct_servertime = $fct_servertimedata['sec'];
    $fct_serverbias = $fct_servertimedata['minuteswest'];
    $fct_totalbias = "$fct_serverbias – $fct_clientbias";
    $fct_totalbias = $fct_totalbias * 60;
    $fct_clienttimestamp = $fct_servertime + $fct_totalbias;
    $fct_time = time();
    $fct_year = strftime("%Y", $fct_clienttimestamp);
    $fct_month = strftime("%B", $fct_clienttimestamp);
    $fct_day = strftime("%d", $fct_clienttimestamp);
    $fct_hour = strftime("%I", $fct_clienttimestamp);
    $fct_minute = strftime("%M", $fct_clienttimestamp);
    $fct_second = strftime("%S", $fct_clienttimestamp);
    $fct_am_pm = strftime("%p", $fct_clienttimestamp);
    

    
    header('Content-Type: image/png');

                    // Создание изображения
       $im = imagecreatetruecolor(330, 30);

     // Создание цветов
      $white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
      $grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 215,24,104);
      $black = imagecolorallocate($im, 255,20,147);
      imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);

      // Текст надписи
       $text =
      $fct_day.", ".$fct_month." ".$fct_year."".$fct_hour.":".$fct_minute."".$fct_am_pm." ";
      // Замена пути к шрифту на пользовательский
       $path = 'time/nexa-script-heavy.ttf';
       $font = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/' . $path;


          // Тень
         imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 11, 21, $grey, $font, $text);

         // Текст
         imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);

         imagepng($im);
         imagedestroy($im);
    }

      showclienttime();
        ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте убрать кавычки вокруг этого выражения и замените знак тире на минус

```
$fct_totalbias = "$fct_serverbias – $fct_clientbias";
```

вот так

```
$fct_totalbias = $fct_serverbias - $fct_clientbias;
```

Из-за этой ошибки у вас не происходит корректировки по часовому поясу и просто показывается время UTC

Comment: Да спасибо уже исправил из за этого была ошибка.